# SQL and Database Design Project

Tags: mysql, sql, database

For one of my classes, I have to complete an assignment that requires me to redesign a database and then develop reports on the data that is given to me. I then have to take the reported data and put that in a text file to turn in to prove I have done the assignment. So far, I have created the tables required with the information. I do not know how to develop the reports.

I have attached the assignment page as well that explains what the assignment is. My question is how do I develop these reports so that I can store the queries and the results of the reports in a .txt file? I am just unsure of how to even get started here.

I appreciate all of the help. Thank you!

[Project Requirements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKtR0.png)

Comment: You should ask the teacher. But looks like you have to write the query to generate the report then put that query and the result in a document. But that is just copy/paste. Doesnt mention anything regarding an automate process. But again consult your teacher

Comment: Thank you for the response. The issue is I have asked my teacher many times, but she seems as if she does not even know how to do it. When I ask her, she just asks me how I would go about doing it and doesn't tell me the way I should. I will try to do what you have mentioned. Again, thank you for the help.

Comment: When there is doubt about lenguaje you ask for clarification, In this case you should ask "What you mean by create a report?", my interpretation is create a query and show the result. Other interpretation could be create an UI where user can click and see the report. But dont looks probable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example report for repeat customer should be something like:

```
 SELECT customer_id, count(*)
 FROM sales
 GROUP BY customer_id
 HAVING count(*) > 1
```

That will generate some rows, then copy query and result to your document.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.